# Jquery autoNumeric set a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, autonumeric.js

I want to set the value of a label with autoNumeric but it is not setting the value I tried it like this

```
$('#lblTotal').autoNumeric(data.total);
```

but it is not setting the value anyOne used it ???

Comment: Another question with a plugin. Are you sure about [autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/)? If yes, Have you read docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I should have set the value with autoNumeric but I was not calling 'init'

```
$('#lblTotal').autoNumeric('init');
$('#lblTotal').autoNumeric('set', data.total);
```

To get value with autoNumeric

```
$('#lblTotal').autoNumeric('get');
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$('#lblTotal').autoNumeric('set', data.total);
```

See the link for more info : [autoNumeric 1.9.18](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/)